# Have macro add member and influence constructor

Tags: c++, c++98

What I would like to do is something like the following.

```
class MyClass {
    list<FieldType> allFields;
    ADDFIELD(field1, Type, args);
    ADDFIELD(field2, Type, args);

    MyClass(){
        MAKE_FIELD_LIST();
    }
}
```

and have it expand to

```
class MyClass {
    list<FieldType> allFields;
    Type field1 = Type(args);
    Type field2 = Type(args);
    MyClass(){
        allFields.put(field1);
        allFields.put(field2);
    }
}
```

Where `MAKE_FIELD_LIST()` will put each field added using `ADDFIELD` into the list object `allFields`. I've used macros in the past for simpler things but I can't figure out if there's a way I could store and add to an array of variable names to be used by `MAKE_FIELD_LIST`.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: What do you expect the result of "something like the following" to be? An important step when working with macros is to define what they should expand to.

Comment: @GManNickG have a number of objects where each field is really just a reference to some range in a buffer. There are times when the members will need to all be validated and having them in a list object would make that considerable easier. Other times it is preferable to be able to access a member by name.

Comment: @molbdnilo Agreed. I have edited my question.

Comment: What are FieldType and Type classes? Is Type derived from FieldType? If so, your code is vulnerable to slicing problem.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you might be able to do is instead of using separate members just use a single `tuple`. You could even associate the class with a `map` of strings too access the correct element.

```
class foo
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void AddMember(const T& t) {
        std::tuple_cat(members_, std::make_tuple(t));
    }
private:
    std::tuple<>members_;
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately we're using an old compiler that barely supports C++98. I dream of being able to use C++11 classes.

Comment: really? why haven't you upgraded? It seems silly to me that you're stuck with such a compiler when it's so simple to upgrade.